# write multiple string line in a file

Tags: java

I want to write a file in multiple line in a file. for example:

first  line: `a b c d e f g h i`
second line: `j k l m n o p q r`
third  line: `s t u v w x y z 1`

but the code I made cannot do so. it only prints on one line every time I try to write in it. Here's my code:

```
FileOutputStream write = new FileOutputStream ("file.txt");
PrintStream print = new PrintStream (write);

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(data));
String read;



while ((read = in.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] splited = read.split("\n");
    for (int z = 0; z<splited.length; z++){

        print.print(splited[z]+" ");

    }

}
print.println();
```

how can i fix this?

Comment: Why is there code for `det` and `bw_data` when you never reference that again? Can you please clean up?

Comment: Also as a general suggestion, if you are trying to solve a specific problem, just post code for the specific problem, i.e., writing to file in you case. You'll often find a solution by yourself if you focus on specifics.

Comment: Now what is `data`? And what are you getting in the output file?

Comment: data is the file where i stored the alphabets in a line

Comment: Can you add code that defines `data` please?

Comment: `read = in.readLine()` will read one line so there will be no `\n` in it. Instead of `read.split("\n")` maybe you wanted `read.split("\\s")` (split uses regex and in regex `\\s` represents any white space)?

Comment: File data = new File ("data.txt"); is this what you mean?

Comment: Please make sure the snippet you are giving is correct enough while it is being read by others.

The line BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(data));
 does not make any sense for us. Because "data" is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

You need to move print.println() inside the while loop.

The correct way is as follows :

```
  while ((read = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] splited = read.split("\n");
      for (int z = 0; z<splited.length; z++){

          print.print(splited[z]+" ");

       }
       print.println();  // correct place for println
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

So first of all, `readLine` reads one line, up to a newline, so there is no need to call `split("\n")` because it will always return the string itself.

Second, you never write a newline to the output file, so it ends up having all the lines unrolled in one. You can just modify the line `print.print(splited[z] + " ");` to `print.print(splited[z] + "\n");`.

Answer (score 0):

I have altered your code in a few ways to improve readability and performance.

- I am now using a `BufferedWriter` instead of a `PrintStream`, which has a nice method for writing newlines.
- I am using `try-with-resources`. This is a Java 7+ feature that automatically closes connections, streams, and buffers for you. In your current code I don't see you closing either the reader or the writer. For such a small program this is not a big deal, but it is good practice to close them.
- I used a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop. This is a nice trick I picked up that saves me from defining `read` in a higher scope than I need it (scope-creep).

-

```
try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("file.txt"));
     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(data)))
{
    for (String read = reader.readLine(); read != null; read = reader.readLine()) {
        writer.append(read);
        writer.newLine();
    }
}
```